# hashcat pkzip2 token length exeption

Tags: zip, password-recovery, brute-force

I have a ZipCrypto-encrypted archive and I lost the password. I'm trying to crack it using zip2john and hashcat but I got this error. Is there any way to fix it?

```
Hashfile './test2.txt' on line 1 ($pkzip...bc56acf6bdb6a88836228b*$/pkzip2$): Token length exception

* Token length exception: 1/1 hashes This error happens if the wrong hash type is specified, if the hashes are malformed, or if input is otherwise not as expected (for example, if the --username option is used but no username is present)

No hashes loaded.
```

Command:

> hashcat.bin -a3 -m17220 ./test2.txt ?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a

Hashfile:

> $pkzip2$3*1*1*0*8*24*054a*8087*e9f28495d0bb3dfeddf247b3a78c9d5c46cd0e918c52708904c4dae013bf67e02a7a64d7*1*0*8*24*e6b7*80b5*   *...*   bc56acf6bdb6a88836228b*$/pkzip2$